# Magento Pro Shipping Method Not Loading

Tags: magento

--This is for Magento Pro, ver. 1.11.1.0--

For some reason, my newly added Flat Rate module is breaking Magento's onepage checkout.  After setting a shipping address, it sticks at flashes "loading next step" but the next step never loads. Disabling my new module makes it work again.  Here are relevant config files:

**/app/code/local/TEST/Shipping/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TEST_Shipping>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <depends>
              <Mage_Shipping />
            </depends>
        </TEST_Shipping>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
           <gtshipping>
                <class>TEST_Shipping</class>
            </gtshipping>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <gtshipping_setup>
               <setup>
                    <module>TEST_Shipping</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>directory_setup</use>
                </connection>
           </gtshipping_setup>
            <gtshipping_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>local_read</use>
                </connection>
            </gtshipping_read>
       </resources>
        <sales>
            <shipping>
                <carriers>
                    <flatrate2>
                        <class>TEST_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate2</class>
                    </flatrate2>
                </carriers>
            </shipping>
        </sales>
    </global>
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <flatrate2>
                <active>1</active>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
                <model>test_shipping_model_carrier_flatrate2</model>
                <name>Fixed</name>
                <price>5.00</price>
                <title>Flat Rate</title>
                <type>I</type>
                <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
                <handling_type>F</handling_type>
            </flatrate2>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/TEST/Shipping/etc/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<sections>
<carriers>
<groups>
<flatrate2 translate="label">
                    <label>Flat Rate</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <name translate="label">
                            <label>Method Name</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </name>
                        <price translate="label">
                            <label>Price</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </price>
                        <handling_type translate="label">
                            <label>Calculate Handling Fee</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>shipping/source_handlingType</source_model>
                            <sort_order>7</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </handling_type>
                        <handling_fee translate="label">
                            <label>Handling Fee</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>8</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </handling_fee>
                        <sort_order translate="label">
                            <label>Sort Order</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </sort_order>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                        <type translate="label">
                            <label>Type</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_flatrate</source_model>
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </type>
                        <sallowspecific translate="label">
                            <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                            <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </sallowspecific>
                        <specificcountry translate="label">
                            <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>91</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                            <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                        </specificcountry>
                        <showmethod translate="label">
                            <label>Show Method if Not Applicable</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>92</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </showmethod>
                        <specificerrmsg translate="label">
                            <label>Displayed Error Message</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>80</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </specificerrmsg>
                        <model translate="label">
                              <label>Model</label>
                              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                              <sort_order>900</sort_order>
                              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        </model>
                    </fields>
                </flatrate2>
            </groups>
        </carriers>
    </sections>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/TEST/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate2.php**

```
class TEST_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate2
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{

    protected $_code = 'flatrate2';
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @param Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $data
     * @return Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result
     */
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $freeBoxes = 0;
        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {

                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $freeBoxes += $item->getQty() * $child->getQty();
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                    $freeBoxes += $item->getQty();
                }
            }
        }
        $this->setFreeBoxes($freeBoxes);

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        if ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'O') { // per order
            $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
        } elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'I') { // per item
            $shippingPrice = ($request->getPackageQty() * $this->getConfigData('price')) - ($this->getFreeBoxes() * $this->getConfigData('price'));
        } else {
            $shippingPrice = false;
        }

        $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($shippingPrice);

        if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
            $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

            $method->setCarrier('flatrate2');
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod('flatrate2');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $this->getFreeBoxes()) {
                $shippingPrice = '0.00';
            }


            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

            $result->append($method);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return array('flatrate2'=>$this->getConfigData('name'));
    }

}
```

Anyone have any ideas why it's not displaying? I see no ajax load errors in the console.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! It was due to the naming of the model.  test needed to be capitalized in the model definition for config.